# Crash when create animation in Cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I want to create animation from ExportJson file but it failed to load

It got the error **Assert failed: CCAnimationData not exist!** and crash.
What's wrong with my below code?

```
static const char s_DragonPList[]   = "gfx/character/dragon/dragon_01/A_010.plist";
static const char s_Dragon[]        = "gfx/character/dragon/dragon_01/A_010.png";
static const char s_DragonJSon[]    = "gfx/character/dragon/dragon_01/A_010.ExportJson";
//async loading export file
CCArmatureDataManager::sharedArmatureDataManager()->addArmatureFileInfo(s_Dragon, s_DragonPList, s_DragonJSon);

//Creat armature by name
CCArmature *armature = CCArmature::create("dragon");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know my stupid error. It's because I renamed the ExportJson file.

**I have to get the exact name that CocoStudio exported**

It took me a few hours to find out.

Comment: @kifcaliph: Sorry for my late reply. First, you need to check the name of files same with the files exported from CocoStudio. Besides, don't rename files if you don't know how to modify inside files. This can make error. Last, use static const char *name instead of const char name[]

Comment: my problem resulted from using backslash \ instead of forward slash / which is more portable :)